# Specify a Zod schema with a non-optional but possibly undefined field

Tags: typescript, zod

Is it possible to define a Zod schema with a field that is possibly `undefined`, but non-optional. In TypeScript this is the difference between:

```js
interface IFoo1 {
  somefield: string | undefined;
}

interface IFoo2 {
  somefield?: string | undefined;
}

const schema = z.object({
  somefield: z.union([z.string(), z.undefined()]),
}); // Results in something like IFoo2
```

As far as I can tell using `z.union([z.string(), z.undefined()])` or `z.string().optional()` results in the field being equivalent to `IFoo2`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify a schema that behaves like `IFoo1`.

### Context / Justification

The reason that I might want to do something like this is to force developers to think about whether or not the field should be `undefined`. When the field is optional, it can be missed by accident when constructing objects of that type. A concrete example might be something like:

```js
interface IConfig {
  name: string;
  emailPreference: boolean | undefined;
}
enum EmailSetting {
  ALL,
  CORE_ONLY,
}

function internal(config: IConfig) {
  return {
    name: config.name,
    marketingEmail: config.emailPreference ? EmailSetting.ALL : EmailSetting.CORE_ONLY,
  }
}

export function signup(userName: string) {
  post(internal({ name: userName }));
}
```

This is sort of a contrived example, but this occurs a lot in our codebase with React props. The idea with allowing the value to be `undefined` but not optional is to force callers to specify that, for example, there was no preference specified vs picking yes or no. In the example I want an error when calling `internal` because I want the caller to think about the email preference. Ideally the type error here would lead me to realize that I should ask for email preference as a parameter to `signup`.

Comment: Have you considered using `null` instead of `undefined`? I think it'd be also more explicit as these two values were made to distinguish between a variable not being set/initialised yet (`undefined`) and a variable currently without a specific value (`null`).

Comment: That’s a reasonable suggestion, and probably what I’ll do if there’s no work around, but for my specific use case I was hoping to use `undefined` to represent the absence of a configuration where `null` is a possible configuration. If I pass `null` in to mean “no preference” as well as a possible “preference is `null`“ then there’s a bit of overloading going on. I suppose I could use a bonafide optional type but I was hoping to simply use `undefined`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `transform` function to explicitly set the field you're interested in. It's a bit burdensome, but it works.

```
const schema = z
    .object({
        somefield: z.string().optional(),
    })
    .transform((o) => ({ somefield: o.somefield }));

type IFoo1 = z.infer<typeof schema>;
// is equal to { somefield: string | undefined }
```

Comment: @Souperman I know this is old, but would it have solved your problem?

Answer (score -4):

It seems like `z.optional()` is what you're looking for based on the docs: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#optionals

```
const schema = z.optional(z.string());

schema.parse(undefined); // => returns undefined
type A = z.infer<typeof schema>; // string | undefined
```

Comment: OP is not asking how to make a schema accept `undefined`. The question is whether there "*is a way to specify a schema that behaves like `IFoo1`*", specifically with its `somefield` property being present but `undefined`.