# How to write a zod validator where the inferred type of a property is number|undefined?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, zod

Some definitions exist for an API (types are generated using protocol buffers). I'd rather not touch these.

One of these types, lets call it `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl` has a property that is union type undefined. Like so:

```
interface SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl {
    someProperty: number | undefined
}

function someFuncOutOfMyControl(obj: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl) {}
```

I am trying to write a validator to really assert that the data is in the correct format. I am using zod for this.

```
const validator = z.object({
    someProperty: z.optional(z.number()),
})
```

But the ts compiler doesn't seem to "understand" that `number | undefined` is the same thing as an optional property. So I get this compiler error:

> error TS2322: Type '{ someProperty?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl'.
> Property 'someProperty' is optional in type '{ someProperty?: number | undefined; }' but required in type 'SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl'.
>
> const object: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl = validator.parse(someData)

```
const validator = z.object({
    someProperty: z.union([z.number(), z.undefined()]),
})
const someData = {} as any
const object = validator.parse(someData)

someFuncOutOfMyControl(object)
// Error on the line above:
// Argument of type '{ someProperty?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl'.
// Property 'someProperty' is optional in type '{ someProperty?: number | undefined; }' but required in type 'SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl'.
```

How can I write the zod validation so that the inferred type becomes "correct" according to the interface? In other words, how do I write a validator for this?:

```
interface SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl {
    someProperty: number | undefined
}
```

I tried using a union:

```
const validator = z.object({
    someProperty: z.union([z.number(), z.undefined()]),
})
```

But the result is the same...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify a Zod schema with a non-optional but possibly undefined field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477015/specify-a-zod-schema-with-a-non-optional-but-possibly-undefined-field)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution to the actual problem, which might not be applicable to what you're working with. But I thought I'd share it at least.

Since you can't edit `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl`.

You could extend it instead and make the fields optional with `Partial`. Like this:

```js
interface SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl {
  someProperty: number | undefined;
}

type MyInterface = Partial<SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl>;

const validator: z.ZodType<MyInterface> = z.object({
  someProperty: z.union([z.number(), z.undefined()]),
});

const someData = {} as any;

const object: MyInterface = validator.parse(someData);
```

Comment: But the error is still there. The reason you are not seeing it is because you defined `object` as an inferred type from the `validator`. If you explicitly specify `object` as a type of `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl` you should get the error. Try this: `const object: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl = validator.parse(someData);` and the error is still there

Comment: You don't how to explicitly type it when using `ZodType`. If you remove `: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl` you will see that object has type `Partial<SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl>` if you hover it. But i also update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: But the point of my question is that it needs to match the definition exactly. I need `object` to **explicitly** be of type `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl`. If it isn't then I wouldn't catch breaking changes in `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl` at compile-time...

Comment: Oh wait maybe I misunderstood you, gimme a minute

Comment: No, you're right. This is a workaround, I understand what you mean. It could work, but there is a difference between an object having a property that has value undefined vs. not having that property at all so there could be errors.

Comment: I have updated my question. There are functions that take an argument of type `SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl`, where I can't use the `object` variable, since the type definitions are misaligned. Really appreciate you trying to help out btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a tranform to the schema solve your problem:

```
import {z} from "zod"
interface SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl {
    someProperty: number | undefined
}

function someFuncOutOfMyControl(obj: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl) {}

const validator = z.object({
    someProperty: z.number().optional(),
}).transform(o => ({...o, someProperty: o.someProperty }))

const someData = {} as unknown
const object: SomeInterfaceOutOfMyControl = validator.parse(someData)
someFuncOutOfMyControl(object)
```